# "choose file to upload" on webview android kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, android-webview

I have a web view, I add the code to upload files and it works well on 4.3 and 4.2 (galaxy s3) , but it doesn't work on 4.4.2 like galaxy s5 and lg3.

when I click on "choose file" it does not respond and nothing happens...

this my code.

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.com.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by tadmitinteractive on 9/21/14.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String url="http://www.ipets.co.il/wp-login.php";
        initWebView(webView,url);
         // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    private void initWebView(WebView view, String url) {

        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        view.clearHistory();
        view.clearFormData();
        view.clearCache(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                                      Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.setMessage("טוען...");
                dialog.show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                dialog.dismiss();
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });

        view.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);

    }

    UploadHandler mUploadHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
            // Chose a file from the file picker.
            if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public MyWebChromeClient() {

        }

        private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
            String title = url;
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                String host = urlObj.getHost();
                if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                    return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                }
                if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                    String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
            // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.cancel();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;

            // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        // Android 2.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // Android 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
        }

        // Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
            mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }
    };

    class Controller {
        final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

        Activity getActivity() {
            return MainActivity.this;
        }
    }

    // copied from android-4.4.3_r1/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    // package com.android.browser;
    //
    // import android.app.Activity;
    // import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    // import android.content.Intent;
    // import android.net.Uri;
    // import android.os.Environment;
    // import android.provider.MediaStore;
    // import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    // import android.widget.Toast;
    //
    // import java.io.File;
    // import java.util.Vector;
    //
    // /**
    // * Handle the file upload callbacks from WebView here
    // */
    // public class UploadHandler {

    class UploadHandler {
        /*
         * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
         */
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String mCameraFilePath;
        private boolean mHandled;
        private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
        private Controller mController;
        public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
            mController = controller;
        }
        String getFilePath() {
            return mCameraFilePath;
        }
        boolean handled() {
            return mHandled;
        }
        void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                // this result.
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                return;
            }
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
            // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
            // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
            // was written to disk in the in the case that we
            // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
            // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
            if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                    result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                    // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                    // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                    mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mHandled = true;
            mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        }
        void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
            final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
            final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
            final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
            final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
            final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
            // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
            // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
            String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                return;
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Parse the accept type.
            String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
            String mimeType = params[0];
            if (capture.length() > 0) {
                mediaSource = capture;
            }
            if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                // may specify a different capture value.
                for (String p : params) {
                    String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                        // Process key=value parameters.
                        if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                            mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
            mCameraFilePath = null;
            if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                    // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camera directly.
                    startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                    // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                    // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camcorder directly.
                    startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                    // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                    // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                    // recorder.
                    startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                    // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
            // file upload chooser.
            startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
        }
        private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            try {
                mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                try {
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                            Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                    Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
            // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
            // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
            // recorder where available.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                    createSoundRecorderIntent());
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    mController.getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType(type);
            return i;
        }
        private Intent createCameraIntent() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                    File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
            return cameraIntent;
        }
        private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
        private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a well-known issue, unfortunately. Google deliberately disabled it in 4.2, and it's still broken as of 4.4 --https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220

Comment: So what can you do to make it possible to upload a photo?
In a roundabout way or something?

Comment: Yes, quite round- and round- and roundabout. I have a JavaScriptBridge which is invoked by the form to launch a native image chooser, then uploads it separately and injects javascript back into the form to give it a UUID of the image uploaded. The server needs to resolve the upload to the form then. Ridiculously complex for something that should just work.

Comment: @323go , so how i can do it like you ?

Comment: I fleshed out the mechanism in my previous comment. There are a lot of moving parts, and I don't have time to pull it all together into an answer, unfortunately. Took me several days to get it working first time around.

Comment: aahhh ok... sombody can help me ??

Comment: You can upload images *before* Android 4.4 and starting with 4.4.3 again. For 4.4.2, you won't be able to do this. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244001/file-upload-not-working-in-android-4-4-2

Answer (score -1):

here is a full solution for all android versions,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        initWebView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com"); // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void initWebView(WebView webView) {

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearCache(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);
    }

    UploadHandler mUploadHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
            // Chose a file from the file picker.
            if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public MyWebChromeClient() {

        }

        private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
            String title = url;
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                String host = urlObj.getHost();
                if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                    return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                }
                if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                    String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
            // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.cancel();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;

            // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        // Android 2.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // Android 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
        }

        // Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
            mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }
    };

    class Controller {
        final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

        Activity getActivity() {
            return MainActivity.this;
        }
    }

    // copied from android-4.4.3_r1/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    // package com.android.browser;
    //
    // import android.app.Activity;
    // import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    // import android.content.Intent;
    // import android.net.Uri;
    // import android.os.Environment;
    // import android.provider.MediaStore;
    // import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    // import android.widget.Toast;
    //
    // import java.io.File;
    // import java.util.Vector;
    //
    // /**
    // * Handle the file upload callbacks from WebView here
    // */
    // public class UploadHandler {

    class UploadHandler {
        /*
         * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
         */
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String mCameraFilePath;
        private boolean mHandled;
        private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
        private Controller mController;
        public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
            mController = controller;
        }
        String getFilePath() {
            return mCameraFilePath;
        }
        boolean handled() {
            return mHandled;
        }
        void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                // this result.
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                return;
            }
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
            // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
            // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
            // was written to disk in the in the case that we
            // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
            // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
            if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                    result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                    // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                    // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                    mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mHandled = true;
            mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        }
        void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
            final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
            final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
            final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
            final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
            final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
            // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
            // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
            String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                return;
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Parse the accept type.
            String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
            String mimeType = params[0];
            if (capture.length() > 0) {
                mediaSource = capture;
            }
            if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                // may specify a different capture value.
                for (String p : params) {
                    String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                        // Process key=value parameters.
                        if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                            mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
            mCameraFilePath = null;
            if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                    // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camera directly.
                    startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                    // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                    // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camcorder directly.
                    startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                    return;
               } else {
                    // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                    // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                    // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                    // recorder.
                    startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                    // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
            // file upload chooser.
            startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
        }
        private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            try {
                mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                try {
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                            Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                    Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
            // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
            // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
            // recorder where available.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                    createSoundRecorderIntent());
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    mController.getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType(type);
            return i;
        }
        private Intent createCameraIntent() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                    File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
            return cameraIntent;
        }
        private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
        private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        }
    }
}
```

For 4.4.2 Use this. This is a demo application link. download and import in your workspace. 
http://applusform.com/down/AgateWebViewFileUpload_AndroidEclipse.zip