# File Upload Not working in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an app using phonegap. The app works fine on all android versions. But the file upload feature on this app does not work on Android 4.4.2. I have googled a lot on this issue, and all I have found is that Google has disabled this feature for Android 4.4.2.

Is there no work around at all? I am really in need of a solution to this problem. It would be great help if someone can suggest a solution to this issue.

Comment: A file upload feature in Android? What do you mean exactly? I do that every day with 4.4. Well not with phonegap. So what do you try to say?

Comment: if you mean the input type="file" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat

Comment: try creating a plugin. Phonegap has given support to use native functionalities. create a plugin using that.
In my project i tried the same for one week yet i cant upload. So i switched to plugin, i made it in a day.

Answer (score 2):

There's no chance to get file uploads working in a `WebView` on Android 4.4.2.

Nevertheless, the `onclick` or `onchange` events are still fired on the `<input type="html">` element.

This means you can either get the file there via JavaScript or call a Java method from those event handlers and do the file upload manually.

For Cordova, there's an issue here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294

... and a workaround here:

https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser