# How do i upload files in android?

Tags: android, webview

After screwing around for so many days, i finally found a workaround for uploading files through webview in Android 4+ i am using AgateWebView. [link in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101065/choose-file-to-upload-on-webview-android-kitkat-4-4-2). however, i cannot get it to work as per my requirement. i want a webkit webview which extends an activity and still uses the AgateWebview for uploading files.

here is my code, i am unable to extend activity. i know i am doing it wrong, but this was what i have tried so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends MOMLActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MOMLWebKit.init(getMomlView());

    this.loadApplication("moml/applicationInfo.xml");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
//          getMomlView().getRoot().runCommand("function.root.onMenuKey", null);
//            return true;
//        }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

This webview seems to load an .xml file instead of an activity layout xml and also instead of extending `Activity`, it extends `MOMLActivity`

Comment: you run the demo code. which is provide at the end of answer??

Comment: yes, i ran the demo project which was linked in a comment below his answer.

Comment: try this answer....... http://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907/3678308

Comment: dude that answer clearly says "** //For Android 4.1**" . IT does NOT work beyond Android 4.1. read the code.